# subsetting on a factor column parsed by readHTMLTable return no result

Tags: r

I ran into a weird subsetting problem. The problem is that I can subset one column but I cannot subset the other. Both columns seemed to have been parsed by readHTMLTable the same way.

The code to replicate

```
require(XML)
theurl <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchanges"
html <- htmlParse(theurl)
seData <- readHTMLTable(html)[[2]]
names(seData) = c("Rank","EX","Economy","HQ","MarketCap","TradeValue")
seData = transform(seData,MarketCap = as.numeric(gsub(",","",MarketCap)))
seData = transform(seData,TradeValue = as.numeric(gsub(",","",TradeValue)))
```

I want to subset for Indian Stock Exchange, so I used:

```
> subset(seData,seData$Economy == "India")
[1] Rank       EX         Economy    HQ         MarketCap  TradeValue
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> subset(seData,seData$Economy == " India")
[1] Rank       EX         Economy    HQ         MarketCap  TradeValue
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I don't get any rows back, despite having validated that there are two rows that should satisfy the condition, but I can easily do the same thing to the other column "EX":

```
> subset(seData,seData$EX == "JSE Limited")
   Rank          EX      Economy           HQ MarketCap TradeValue
17   17 JSE Limited  SouthAfrica Johannesburg       903        287
```

I've ran other functions and the two columns look exactly the same..

```
> sapply(seData,class)
      Rank         EX    Economy         HQ  MarketCap TradeValue 
  "factor"   "factor"   "factor"   "factor"  "numeric"  "numeric" 
> levels(seData$Economy)
 [1] " Australia"             " Brazil"                " Canada"               
 [4] " China"                 " Germany"               " Hong Kong"            
 [7] " India"                 " Japan"                 " Russia"               
...
> levels(seData$EX)
 [1] "Australian Securities Exchange"   "BME Spanish Exchanges"           
 [3] "BM&F Bovespa"                     "Bombay Stock Exchange"           
 [5] "Deutsche BÃ¶rse"                  "Hong Kong Stock Exchange"        
 [7] "JSE Limited"                      "Korea Exchange"                  
 ...
```

What did I miss? What is wrong with the subsetting command I used? :(

```
subset(seData,seData$Economy == " India")
```

Comment: Most likely your data has some weird characters which is typical when parsing data from web. e.g. if I run your code, i see `Â India` instead of just `India`

Comment: Also, inside a `subset` call you don't need to rename the data set, i.e. once your character set is right, `subset(seData, Economy == " India")` should work.

Comment: Thanks for that @shujaa, will save some typing power from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, this issue occurs mostly due to non standard characters in data which I am guessing happens due character encoding settings.

Instead of using `subset` you may want to use standard `[` subsetting with `grepl`
`grepl` will give you vector of logical values , which you then use to subset your dataframe. This allows you to do partial matching as well as an added bonus

```
> seData[grepl('India', seData$EX),]
   Rank                               EX Economy     HQ MarketCap TradeValue
11   11 National Stock Exchange of India Â India Mumbai      1234        442
```

**EDIT**

`grepl` will also work inside `subset` function

```
> subset(seData,  grepl('India', seData$EX) )
   Rank                               EX Economy     HQ MarketCap TradeValue
11   11 National Stock Exchange of India Â India Mumbai      1234        442
```

Comment: Thanks geektrader! Can't believe I spent hours on this... it works!